# Woocommerce Bookings - programmatically adjust availability

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I am trying to control the availability of booking forms programmatically on my website. I have updated the post meta with an array of data needed for the availability and it shows in the backend of the product as expected absolutely fine. However when I control this programmatically the booking form on the frontend of the website doesnt update. Can someone advise how to do this? Does it use some kind of mini cache or do I have to flush it or something? Ive tried everything! It is set up to change the availability as soon as a user updates their profile for the first time, as the times will be swapped out for variables set on their profile.

This is how im going about updating in code, adding my changed availability to an array and updating the meta. Showing in the backend great just not on the front end.

```
  //when profile builder saves, update the meta
  add_action('wppb_edit_profile_success', 'updateAvailability');
  function updateAvailability() {

    $availabilities = array();

     $availability = array(
       'type' => 'time:1', //Replace time:range with the type you need
       'bookable' => 'yes',
       'priority' => 10,
       'from' => wc_booking_sanitize_time( "09:00" ),
       'to' => wc_booking_sanitize_time( "17:00" ),
     );
     array_push($availabilities, $availability);

     $availability = array(
        'type'      => 'time:2',
        'bookable'  => 'yes',
        'priority'  => 10,
        'from'      => wc_booking_sanitize_time( "07:00" ),
        'to'        => wc_booking_sanitize_time( "13:00" ),
     );
     array_push($availabilities, $availability);

     delete_post_meta( $booking_id, '_wc_booking_availability' );
     add_post_meta( $booking_id, '_wc_booking_availability', $availabilities );

  }
```

When i check the booking for the form still shows the initial value that was set on creation.

Thanks, any assistance hugely appreciated here!

Comment: "*The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem***". Give us a more complete code version please as this is  not testable.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec added more code.

Comment: Where are you using this code (or how)? which hook? see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @LoicTheAztec added the hook code. Its on save of the profile. So the times are set on their profile builder then my intention is to use those answers to swap these times out for variables, but it doesnt yet change the times on the form if you update the meta.

Comment: It doesn't work as i think that you also need to alter the custom WC Bookings related tables `wp_wc_bookings_availability` and `wp_wc_bookings_availabilitymeta`